# Lombok not working with "Android room". Gives "error: Cannot find getter for field"

Tags: android, lombok, android-room, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm using Lombok in android studio 3.0 preview with gradle 3.0.0-alpha1. I have following two annotation processor in my dependency:

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
```

Now, If I use annotations from both dependencies in same class like:

```
@Entity(tableName = "test")
@Getter
public final class TestEntity {...}
```

It'll produce an error, that is:

```
error: Cannot find getter for field.
```

But if I remove any one of them, it'll work fine.

Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reorder your annotation processor declarations. Move lombok up above the room compiler

Answer (score 4):

From Edwin Nyawoli answer, i just want to make it clear

In your build.gradle module file, reorder Lombok dependency above Room dependency

```
// Lombok
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombok_version"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombok_version"

// Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using val in your model class? If yes, change to var

Comment: I'm writing code in java not in scala or kotlin, so i'm not using any of these var or val.

Answer (score -3):

Try do it, it works for me.

```
public String getmState(){
    return mState;
}
```

change to

```
public String getMState(){
    return mState;
}
```

Comment: That's an explicitly defined getter method.  The original question was in regards to Lombok (https://projectlombok.org/)